# Disable source printing in ipdb

Tags: python, debugging, ipdb

How do I disable the default printing of source context in ipdb? I'm calling ipdb from within Emacs realgud so I don't need to see the source i the ipdb prompt.

The code

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

can be executed inside the ipdb shell itself but

```
ipdb.set_trace(context=5)
```

fails as

```
*** TypeError: set_trace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

Is this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

The way [python trepan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan) and [trepan3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan3k) handle this is via `set autolist`. Come to think of it, all of my debuggers handle it this way and so do some of the ruby debuggers like rdebug since that's where I got the idea from.